# If a website gives a 302 HTTP response code, can I get the original link's raw HTML still?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying, in Python, using the requests library, to get the HTML for a website that automatically redirects to another one. How do I avoid this and get the HTML for the original site, if possible? I know it exists and has HTML for it because I have accessed it via the Chrome view-source function. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but I saw it in the sidebar and figured I'd answer for future readers.

If you set `allow_redirects` to `False` while using requests, it will stop at the first 302 and allow you to get the source code.

So, `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)`

[Source](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't. If the web server is returning a 302 unless it decides to include the old html(which would be very odd ) you are basically out of luck.

Now if you hit it with a web browser and it doesn't redirect you, then perhaps it is doing something like user agent sniffing and redirecting based on that. So in that case you would need your code to claim to be that ua.